# Backbone collection consists of only 1 object of objects, how can I make each nested object a model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

My data consists of an object that has nested objects with each key being the id, I want to parse the collection `response.payload` but when I do the collection is returned as 1 object containing the nested objects. Can anyone advise on how I can make each nested object a model?

**JS**

```
    var data = {
    "payload": {
        "020": {
            "sessions": ["SES1", "SES2", "SES3", "SES4"],
            "account": [],
            "tag": []
        },
        "650": {
            "sessions": ["SES11", "SES12", "SES13"],
            "account": ["ACCT1", "ACC2", "ACC3"],
            "tag": []
        },
        "880": {
            "sessions": ["SES900", "SES901"],
            "account": ["abc", "DEF"],
            "tag": ["TAG5", "TAG53"]
        }
    }
};

var SearchCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    parse: function(response) {
        console.log(response.payload);
        return response.payload;
    }
});

var searchCollection = new SearchCollection(data, {parse: true});
console.log(searchCollection.toJSON());
```

Do I need to loop the response in parse and create model with a key id instead or create a model and do some parsing there?

**JS Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/t6w0bcu6/22/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would "loop the response in parse and create model with a key id". Here's one way to do it.

```
var SearchCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    parse: function(response) {
      var models = [];
      _.each(response.payload,(value, key)=>{
        value.id = key;
        models.push(new Backbone.Model(value))
      })
        return models;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t6w0bcu6/23/